# Add auto line break in LibreOffice Draw (text warp)

Tags: libreoffice-draw

Is it possible to add an auto line break to a shape (text warp) in LibreOffice Draw?

[image]

I found [this post on the LibreOffice forum](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/26199/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-draw/) but the answer seems to be outdated, I can not find the options described.

Comment: "an auto line break to a shape", rectangle, texbox?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio In this case it's a rectangle, but eventually I might want to change different shapetypes. But for now I want to change a single shape not (all shapes of) a shape type. maybe I'm using the wrong syntax, now I hope it's clear what I want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the shape, select Edit Style. (Or select the shape, click Format -> Styles -> Edit Style).

[image: IMG:]

2. On the window that appears, select Text tab, enable "Word wrap text in shape".

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Thx, this will change the style of all shapes, I just want to change the style of a single shape (not one type, really just a single shape). Maybe I'm using the wrong syntax, now, I hope it's clear what I want.